# Displaying View Controller within a UITabBarController programatically in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift5, xcode11

In my app when the user logs in, they should be taken to a welcome screen, which is part of a TabBarController. But for some reason, when I run the following lines, the welcome screen (HomeScreenViewController) shows up without the TabBar navigation buttons at the bottom.

```
let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeScreenViewController
self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Inspired by another StackOverflow post, I tried this, but it didn't work either:

```
let homeController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier:Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController)
(TabBarController.currentInstance?.selectedViewController as?UINavigationController)?.pushViewController(homeController!, animated: true)
```

For reference, the name of my UITabBarController class is TabBarController and the identifier can be accessed via

```
Constants.Storyboard.tabBarCont
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this..

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeScreenViewController
let anyOtherViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: anyOtherViewController) as? AnyOtherViewController

        homeViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "home_image"),tag: 1)
        anyOtherViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Other",image:UIImage(named: "other") ,tag:2)
        tabBarController.viewControllers = [homeViewController, anyOtherViewController] 

        window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this after login:

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let centerViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as! TabBarController
        centerViewController.selectedIndex = 0
        centerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
            appDelegate.window = window
        }
        appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = centerViewController
        self.present(centerViewController!, animated: false, completion: nil)
```